# I want to change query the date between current date but with different times?

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to change 2016-11-20 with current date

```
SELECT services, loket, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN STATUS IN ('7','4') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Total_queue, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN STATUS = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS balance_queue, SUM( CASE WHEN STATUS = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS nomer_queue  
FROM tabelqueue 
WHERE STATUS IN ('7','4') 
    AND get_ticket BETWEEN '2016-11-21 00:00:01' AND '2016-11-21 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY services
```

Comment: Don't you care about exactly midnight? And what about `23:59:59.003`? Instead of `BETWEEN` use proper closed-open ranges `[,) i.e. >=,<`. And what about timezones? It's important to understand how to work with dates and times correctly, otherwise you just create headaches for yourself later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the condition as:

```
WHERE STATUS IN ('7', '4') AND
      get_ticket >= CURDATE() AND get_ticket < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), interval 1 day)
```

Your original condition should probably be written as:

```
WHERE STATUS IN ('7', '4') AND
      get_ticket >= DATE('2016-11-21') AND
      get_ticket < DATE_ADD(DATE('2016-11-21'), interval 1 day)
```

Notes:

- Don't use times when you only want dates.
- You *could* do `DATE(get_ticket) = CURDATE()`.  This is easy to read but the query cannot take advantage of an index on `get_ticket`, if that is available and appropriate.
- If `STATUS` is a number, do not use quotes around the constants.  Quoted numbers are misleading both for people and for the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GETDATE() function; for example:

```
WHERE STATUS IN ('7','4') 
    AND get_ticket BETWEEN GETDATE() AND '2016-11-21 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY services
```

This gives the current date and time; if you want it to start at midnight today you can use:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 102)
```

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you were using MySql; GETDATE is a T-SQL function which I don't thinj is available - CURDATE should work.